# Is there a way to setup 2 separate DB pools on a Sequelize connection with replication enabled?

Tags: node.js, heroku, optimization, database-connection, sequelize.js

[Read Replication Docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html#read-replication)

I'm essentially trying to decouple the number of connections my master and slaves get in order to maximize the number available connections and load across my read replicas. I'm currently looking for a quick an easy optimization for a Heroku hosted application (40 dynos) that is currently at it's connection limit whenever request volume is at it's peak.

My attempts to optimize request throughput with [pgbouncer-stunnel](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer) have all failed and am wondering if Sequelize pooling just wasn't playing well with pgbouncer's pool. One thing I didn't try was just setting `pool: false` (I'm on Sequelize version 3). There are of course other optimizations I need to make but increasing the number of read-only connections would relieve the volume this app is encountering the most.

Example of how we're instantiating postgres Sequelize postgres connection below:

```
    let seqOptions: Sequelize.Options = {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        logging: function (sql: string) {
            if (pgConfig.logging) {
                helpers.logDebug('sequelize ' + sql);
            }
        },
        pool: {
            maxConnections: pgConfig.maxConnections,
            minConnections: pgConfig.minConnections,
        },

        define: {
            timestamps: false // true by default
        },

        timezone: config.timezone
    };

    if (config.pg.useSSLDBConnection) {
        seqOptions.dialectOptions = {
            ssl: config.pg.useSSLDBConnection,
            timeout: 10,
            returning: true
        };
    };

    if (config.pg.useReadReplication && !config.pg.separateReadWrite) {
        let masterUrl = url.parse(config.pgWrite.url);
        let username = masterUrl.auth.split(':')[0];
        let password = masterUrl.auth.split(':')[1];
        let databaseName = masterUrl.path.split('/').pop();
        seqOptions.replication = {
            write: {
                host: masterUrl.hostname,
                port: masterUrl.port,
                database: databaseName
            },
            read: _.map(config.pgReadReplicas, (readUrl) => {
                let _readUrl = url.parse(readUrl);
                let databaseName = _readUrl.path.split('/').pop();
                return ({
                    host: _readUrl.hostname,
                    port: _readUrl.port,
                    database: databaseName
                });
            })
        };

        let connection = new Sequelize(null, username, password, seqOptions);
        return new SQLContext(connection);
```